# Calculate age using DOB column

Tags: ssis, expression, etl, datediff, derived-column

I have dob column how can i calculate age by using DOB column in derived column ?
I tried using  as below but this throws an error .

```
 datediff(yy, Dob,getdate())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following expression:

```
DATEDIFF("yy" , [DOB], GETDATE())
```

**References:**

- [DATEDIFF (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/datediff-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)